# Adobe AIR progress event traces value but wont allow me to update a text field during load progress

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a FlashBuilder AIR Android project which I am trying to setup a loading progress screen.

Here's what I have:

1. User selects page
2. Loader starts to load SWF
3. Progress event shows % loading and bar.scaleX 0 to 1 for progress bar representation
4. hide progress ui and show page / loaded swf

This all works fine for web and the AIR simulator, but when it is tested on the device, the precentage loaded, even the progress bars scaleX values are all traced correctly however they do not update visually?

Anyone know how to fix this?
or a reason for this?

Thanks

D

Comment: first idea - possible font issue. However, you should show your code. Otherwise - it's just guessing

Comment: It's not a font issue, I've created a text field with system fonts, one using embedded fonts and same result. And to top that off I am manipulating a movieclip on the scaleX property from 0 to 1. None update. I've also placed a gif into the fla as a timeline animation and it also doesn't play. I even placed play() and gotoAndPlay(1) on the animation sequence to ensure it plays and it still doesn't... Baffled... seems AIR for android cant do anything when loading is in progress.

Comment: it also doesn't explain why it works fine for the SWF online and AIR Simulator. AIR Android limitation is my best guess.

Comment: Did you load in the progress bar externally? There are some restrictions on loading assets externally that have timeline code on mobile (although I'm assuming the progress bar is not included with your swf, or you are not packaging it with the app).

Comment: All assets are part of the SWC which is attached to the main project. It's a FlashBuilder project, flash is just used for asset creation and library SWC generation which gets compiled into the project. So the app has access to all assets it needs for the generic application this includes page loading assets, they even trace out as in existance and display on the screen. Typically I do not put any AS3 code in my timelines as I manage all this via FlashBuilder.

Comment: PS. Just tested this on the mac on a shaitPad3 and it works fine. Testing on Galaxy Note 10.1 (Android 4.4.x) and Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.2.x) both loose all ability to play timeline animation and update the progress bars scaleX property or 2 text fields correctly during a progress loader. I've now tested this with a standard loader written by myself based on Adobe Live Docs AS3 and using GreenSocks MaxLoader. Same result. Next up I will try the file system, see if I can file stream and do things at the same time and then some how get the file stream to be read as a movieclip.

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Comment: This of course has been done many times without any problem. This should be your first clue: you are doing something wrong and the only way for us to help you is to see your code.

Comment: The solution was to use filestream instead of urlloader or other web loading solutions which worked but performed really slow. Now I dont even need a progress bar.